# JOOQ get POJO object with another POJO - foreign key in table

Tags: java, jooq

I'm new at using JOOQ and I have problem but I can't find solution. I have simple database with 2 tables: `Sellers` and `Clients` - sql below:

```
CREATE TABLE Sellers
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);


CREATE TABLE Clients
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
seller_id int,
FOREIGN KEY (seller_id) REFERENCES Sellers(id)
);
```

`Client` has `foreign key` and it defines which `Seller` is assigned to him.

I would like to get clients from database using JOOQ but using `join()` also get `Seller` object to each of client. Is it possible? If so how to do that? Here's my POJO objects:

```
public class Seller {
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    ...
    //setters and getters here
    ...
}

public class Client {
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty sellerId = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    //private Seller seller; //not working
    ...
    //setters and getters here
    ...
}
```

And here's my JOOQ code to get clients:

```
context.select()
    .from(CLIENTS)
    .join(SELLERS)
    .on(CLIENTS.ID.eq(SELLERS.ID))
    .fetchInto(Client.class);
```

What should I change to get what I want?

Comment: `Client` has `seller` as an object. The DB has `seller_id` as an `int`. Does JOOQ resolve that automatically?

Comment: @bradimus it resolves seller_id as int automatically but as you can see in my Client class I also tried to add object Seller seller but it didn't resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the conversation [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/jooq-user/EiBGfsmtFtc) between Lukas Eder (the author of jOOQ) and some other jOOQ users. Garrett Wilson's use case looks very similar to yours (where you have `Client`:`Seller`, he has `Book`:`Author`).

there's quite a bit said, but by design it seems jOOQ isn't geared toward automatically hydrating a `Seller` instance within your fetched `Client` record. this is the classic N+1 problem associated with ORMs (i.e. multiple queries against your table of sellers triggered by a query for clients).

one proposal is to to break your join up into discrete queries:

```
select * from Client where ...
select * from Seller where id in (select seller_id from Client where ...)
```

... and then do your `client.setSeller()` type logic somewhere in your application. in this case you avoid the N+1 problem, and you don't need to rely on writing custom any `RecordMapper` types.

i'm no jOOQ expert, but the approach i used in the past when i had columns from hierarchical types being returned in one query worked out pretty well for me:

1. define a custom record mapper to map your jOOQ `Record` to your domain type/POJO
2. define a custom `RecordMapperProvider` and use it to create `DSLContext` singleton that gets passed around to whatever components do your querying (e.g. through dependency injection)
3. using the aforementioned `DSLContext`, compose your query and use `fetchInto()` to designate your target type (which should have been accounted for in your `RecordMapperProvider`)

in the conversation referenced earlier, Lukas drops a [link](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/) to the documentation about using custom `RecordMapperProvider` instances, so this might very well be idiomatic.

hope that helps.